# Way of implementing LinkedList, Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, append, nodes

I'm reading this book and there is this chapter on liked list and it starts with the implementation of a single linked list, it goes like this:

Creating a Linked List:

```
class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;

    public Node(int d) {
        data = d;
    }

    void appendToTail(int d) {
        Node end = new Node(d);
        Node n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
    }
}
```

My questions:

First: I can't understand how this works. Is this really that complex to understad it or I'm missing something?

Second: Can this "Node" class be considered a linked list? I know it's missing some functionality but is this a linked list on it's own?

Third: I've googled LinkedList implementations in java and glanced at the original class in java api and it's a totally different approach. To what approach should I stick?

Comment: What didn't you understand?

Comment: You're missing something; it doesn't get much simpler than this. You should stick to an approach you understand: step through it on paper, it's the best way to learn.

Comment: What *specifically* don't you understand? There's almost no code there to understand.

Comment: Write, or copy, a program using this class, then step through it with pencil and paper. Draw a new box each time a constructor is called. Use an arrow pointing to the box to represent a reference to the object. Have an eraser handy for when things change.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan Ok, thanks I will do so.

Comment: OMG, @Patricia Shanahan. I remember you and your outstanding posts from the good old days of comp.lang.java.programmer. Good to see you're alive, not like this old usenet group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this code is that the `Node` class is a *node* and a *linked list* at the same time, which is confusing. Other than that it should be pretty straightforward.

```
class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;
```

The `next` holds the next node in a list. If it is the last node, it holds `null`. The `data` is a data associated with this node, which in this case is of type `int`(BTW it should be `final`).

```
public Node(int d) {
    data = d;
}
```

This is a simple `constructor` which just copies the argument to its field. It represent the head of the list and a list itself.

```
void appendToTail(int d) {        
    Node n = this;
    while (n.next != null) {
        n = n.next;
    }
```

This is where find the meet. I've rearranged the code a bit to make it easier to understand. The `appendToTail` method adds a node at the and of the list. In the code above it traverses the list (starting with `this` which is a head of the list) to find the *last* node (the one with `next` field set to `null`).

```
    Node end = new Node(d);
    n.next = end;
}
```

Here a new node is created and added as the next node to the current *last* thus making it the last node of the list.

Comment: `which is confusing` -> No it is not. LinkedList is generally implemented in this way only.

Comment: @RohitJain Well actually you have a seperate LinkedList and Node classes in standard Java. The Node is a `private static` inner class of LinkedList, but it is a seperate class.

Comment: @RohitJain i think most implementations are a LinkedList class that only contains a single reference to a root node and the LinkedList class operates on the nodes. in OPs example, the node class itself does operations which is weird design.

Comment: From a language independent computer science point of view, a node with a next pointer is generally used. The `LinkedList` is a Java class that implements `List`. You can still have a conceptual linked list with just the `Node` class.

Comment: @SteveKuo I agree it is a conceptual linked list. At the same time it is not intuitive to have `appendToTail` method on a `Node`. It would be more intuitive to name the class `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Next is the link to the next piece of data.

[Data|next->][Data|next->] .... [   ]

The next is like a pointer, it points to the next Node.

appendToTail creates a Node and the links.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the **Node** class should be as small as it can be. The main functionality of the Node is;

- Storing the value of Node
- Storing a reference (or a pointer) to the **next Node** instance

The simplest way to write a Node class should be similiar as above;

```
public class Node<E> {
    protected E value;
    protected Node<E> next;

    public Node(E value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then, you can write a custom **LinkedList** implementation using this generic **Node** class.

On that particular example code in your question, they have implemented the **append** method inside the **Node** class and that's not a good practice in my opinion. Instead, an append should be in the **LinkedList** class because that method is not in the responsibility of the **Node** class.

#### Append Method in LinkedList

Methods implemented on different sources can vary. But the append method itself is seen mostly the same. You have to understand the logic of the append method before implementing it.

When a linked list is empty, the head points to a null value. Head is the field, member of the LinkedList class which stores the starting Node of the Linked List.

As you append values to the Linked List, at first, head is stored with the first appended value, and then, the second value will be a new node, which head's next reference or pointer points to. And so on. You can check the states down below;

```
// Initial state of the Linked List
// Head is null

HEAD = NULL

// Append 40 to the Linked List 
// Head stores value 40, but next reference is null.

HEAD(40) --> NULL

// Append 10

HEAD(40) --> (10) --> NULL

// Append 20

HEAD(40) --> (10) --> (20) --> NULL

// Append 50

HEAD(40) --> (10) --> (20) --> (50) --> NULL

// Append 100

HEAD(40) --> (10) --> (20) --> (50) --> (100) --> NULL
```

As it is obvious, Linked List always ends up with a NULL reference, which is very useful when traversing in the list. There have to be a point, a mark that implies "This is the end of the road, terminate traversing this road"

You can also check a minimalistic simple Linked List implementation I've written for this example down below;

## Minimalist Implementation Of LinkedList

```
public class CustomLinkedList<E> {

    private Node<E> head;

    public CustomLinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    public void appendToList(E value) {
        if(head == null)
            head = new Node<E>(value);
        else {
            Node<E> temp = head;

            // get the end node into the temp
            while(temp.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;

            // temp is the tail now
            // append new Node next to the tail
            temp.next = new Node<E>(value);
        }
    }

    public void printList() {
        if(head == null)
            return;

        System.out.print("List: ");

        Node<E> temp = head;
        while( temp != null ) {
            System.out.print(temp.value.toString() + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

## Demo Code

```
public class DemoCustomLinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomLinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new CustomLinkedList<>();

        linkedList.appendToList(40);
        linkedList.appendToList(10);
        linkedList.appendToList(20);
        linkedList.appendToList(50);
        linkedList.appendToList(100);

        linkedList.printList();
    }

}
```

Demo Output

```
List: 40 10 20 50 100
```